# How to send FCM without sound or vibration?

Tags: firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I am send push notification to device. Currently it send with vibration and sound:

```
apns: {
    headers: {
        'apns-priority': '10',
    },
    payload: {
        aps: {
            sound: 'default',
        }
    },
},
android: {
    priority: "high",
    notification: {
        sound: 'default',
    }
},
```

How I can send notification without sound or vibration? I only want notification display on screen and wake up screen if locked.

Thanks!